# How do I migrate from systray to AppIndicators?

Tags: application-development, indicator, ayatana

I am considering forking Parcellite and making it use AppIndicators now that Ubuntu has dropped support for systray. How different are these, and are there any "getting started" guides on AppIndicators yet?

Comment: There is an active fork of Parcellite that is about to enter Debian, ClipIt. As Parcellite's packager, I'm considering simply upgrading users from Parcellite to ClipIt. You might want to contribute to this project. http://sourceforge.net/projects/gtkclipit/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- [Homepage](http://unity.ubuntu.com/projects/appindicators/) on unity.ubuntu.com
- [Design Guidelines](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CustomStatusMenuDesignGuidelines)
- [Implementation Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators) with code samples
- [Mailing List](https://launchpad.net/~ayatana-dev)

Answer (score 4):

API documentation is available here -

- http://people.canonical.com/~ted/libappindicator/current/

Some information are also avaiable at Ubuntu Wiki -- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators#Technical%20Resources

Answer (score 4):

It's not really an answer to the question, but a remark about the point of Application Indicators.

You actually **do not migrate** from System Tray to Application Indicators. These are different things and you shouldn't use indicators for all the various things you used tray for. The purpose of indicators was to stop the malicious exploitation of tray and you shouldn't try to migrate this exploitation to indicators.

Take your time and read carefully and with meaning the paragraph dealing with this issue:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CustomStatusMenuDesignGuidelines#Does%20your%20program%20need%20a%20custom%20status%20menu?